# SwipeRefreshLayout not working when first item has a height of 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

`SwipeRefreshLayout` does not work (animation not shown, `onRefresh` not called) when the first item in the `RecyclerView` within the `SwipeRefreshLayout` has a height of zero.

You can check out a test project [on Github](https://github.com/fweigl/ThrowAwaySwipe) that shows this.

My question is: can this effect be circumvented? 
In my actual project, due to circumstances not in my hand (Ad library)the first item of my list *will* sometimes have a height of `0`, so setting it to `View.GONE` or height to `1` is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

Found an workaround: Put `RecyclerView` to into additional view:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

it cause additional overdraw, but works

few more suggestions found here: https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/issues/74

Comment: this is working for me, but did you know why this is happening???

Comment: @DeePanShu i had no time to debug recyclerView, but seems to me it does not trigger SwipeRefreshLayout callbacks in case first item have zero height.

Comment: I solved it by giving 1dp padding to bottom of layout and All View gone

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a callback from the ad library you should be able to work around the bug by adding and removing the advertisement item from your RecyclerView.Adapter depending on whether or not the ad view has content to display.